# I can't assign script from another object. Is there smth wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeteorRangeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PlayerController PlayerController; // It has to be script
    [SerializeField] GameObject Player; // no problem with assigning this
    [SerializeField] Transform playerTransform;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 playerPos; 
    [SerializeField] bool canGo;
    [SerializeField] GameObject meteor;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
          playerTransform = Player.GetComponent<Transform>();
          PlayerController= Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>(); //*The Problem Is Here*
            //PlayerController Cannot Be Assigned
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print(PlayerController.IdleTime); //to test it I printed
        playerPos = Player.transform.position;
   //I tried to take idle time from Player controller  here.

        if (PlayerController.IdleTime > 2)
        {
            canGo = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canGo = false;
        }

        if (canGo == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(playerPos.x, playerPos.y, playerPos.z);
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Invoke("SetActiveFalse",2f);
        }
    }

    void SetActiveFalse()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        meteor.SetActive(true);
        Invoke("MeteorSetActiveFalse", 2f);
    }

    void MeteorSetActiveFalse()
    {
        meteor.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I can't assign it.

I researched it but I couldn't find anything different.

I know it's a very easy question, also I assigned game object player, in it there is a script named PlayerController, and there is a variable named idle time please help me

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why instead of going through the field `Player` at all not directly drag the player into the `PlayerController` field in the Inspector?

Comment: Is it because the variable name is the same as the type name? Trying renaming it to PlayerController playerController; (lowercase p)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, that's my first try to answer on topic on Stack Overflow, so hope you will be patient to my mistakes.

1. Can you say, are you sure, that Player object has a PlayerController script on him?
2. I think you must use

```cs
var isControlSetted = Player.TryGetComponent<PlayerController>(out PlayerController);
```

instead of:

```cs
PlayerController= Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
```

Why? So, that can answer on question №1 and after it you can control the logic of working with it when (use AddComponent for example or throw an exception)
3. Okay, even that can't fix your problem if PlayerController setted on inheritor or ancestor of Player gameobject in gameobject hierarchy

I hope I helped you

Edited:

Okay, I was asked to make answer some clearly, so...

First of all, can you show PlayerController script, pls?

Secondary, why I'm asking to use TryGetComponent instead of GetComponent bcs as I commented below getting null value is not a good practice, but if you want - use it.

Let's look on script more closly

I refactored this pls look

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class MeteorRangeController 
    : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PlayerController playerController;
    [SerializeField] GameObject playerObject;
    [SerializeField] Transform playerTransform;
    // [SerializeField] Vector3 playerPos; we don't need this
    // [SerializeField] bool canGo; and this
    [SerializeField] GameObject meteorObject;


    /// <summary>
    /// Method that called once we use this or Awake for init our fields/props
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = playerObject.GetComponent<Transform>(); // there no need to use TryGetComponent bcs Transform is req. for every GO/MB
        playerController= playerObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>(); // there you could use TryGC, but if you use RequireComponentAttribute that's ok
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that's calls every frame
    /// </summary>
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerController.IdleTime <= 2)
            return;
        
        transform.position = playerTransform.position;// i really can't understand what hepenning after this so i stop
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Invoke(nameof(SetActiveFalse),2f);     
    }

    void SetActiveFalse()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        meteorObject.SetActive(true);
        Invoke(nameof(MeteorSetActiveFalse), 2f);
    }

    void MeteorSetActiveFalse()
    {
        meteorObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

So, afterwards GO.GetComponent can return null only if the requested GO did not have a Monobehaviour script.
You can check similar question there https://forum.unity.com/threads/getcomponent-doesnt-works.516839/

Comment: `I think you must use` .. not really.. this is more useful in e.g. collisions if you want to check if a certain component exists .. in this case OP expects this component to exist so you **want** to get an exception if it is not there so you can fix that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @derHugo I'm not agree with this bcs getting null is much worse than getting bool value.
There I just suggested a method for answering on my first question

Comment: it really depends what you are going to do with this `bool` .. I've seen code using this doing `if(Player.TryGetComponent<PlayerController>(out PlayerController)){ ... }` ... so if nothing happens you can spend hours to figure out why until finally finding the place where `TryGetComponent` returns `false` ... if you would rather get an exception you would immediately know where to look at including getting the call stack etc